# Separator tag not found in UWP XAML

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I think the title says it all. When I try to use the `<Separator />` tag to put a line in between elements in a stack panel in a UWP XAML app, I get this: [image]

When I hover over the separator elements it says that `The type Separator cannot be found` and gives the error code XLS0414.

Any ideas?

I've looked at many websites and they all say that I need to use the separator tag for what I'm trying to do, but I can't use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `Separator` UIElement in UWP. `Separator` is a WPF construct, so if you're looking at many websites that all say you need to use the separator flag, they're probably referring to a WPF application or using some toolkit nuget package.

However, you can mimic a Separator using a couple of workarounds.

1. Use a Border that has a thickness defined on only one edge.

```
<Border BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" ... />
```

2. Use a Rectangle that is shaped like a separator

```
<Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" Fill="Black" />
```